# Responsive screen design

Tags: css, responsive-design

Currently the screen design for our application is done for the desktop and laptop resolutions and it needs to be extended to work on for different resolutions like iPad, iPhone and other devices. At most of the places pixels have been used in the css so it needs changes at MANY places.

One idea currently I have to do this is using media queries and try to convert the pixels ato percentages. Is it good to use Media queries or any other better solution for this?

Please suggest...

Comment: Best solution is Media Queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to responsive design, then I would suggest looking at a responsive front-end framework. Even if you dont actually use the framework itself, its still worth it to look through the code and understand how they work, and apply those methods to your site.

- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [Twitter-Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/)
- [HTML KickStart](http://www.99lime.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to make it responsive, you'd need to use media queries, and everything that changes in the queries, you can just position using percentages and floats if you want. That should work.